# Using only reference counting in Rust

Tags: rust

I want to write simple Rust code, while keeping it run time deterministic, and there's no need for memory cycles.

Can I use only reference counted pointers in my code?

Comment: why would you need Rc for that?

Comment: Rc is runt time determinstic. GC isn't. And isn't working with other pointer types means i need to use both owned and borrowed pointers, or i can manage using a single type , simply ?

Comment: Rust's owned pointers are not garbage collected. Rust's references don't own any data to begin with.

Comment: and what is the problem with owned and borrowed? they are there for a reason. Rc is there for situations when standard borrow rules are in the way.

Comment: or you think of using just one pointer type (Rc) for simplicity? (don't)

Comment: Why not use it for simplicity , assuming i can live with the inefficiencies ?

Comment: Typically using `T` and `&T` and avoiding reference counting is simpler. Only use `Rc` where the borrowing rules genuinely do make it impossible to use the simple solution.

Comment: why not? because it wont make it simple, more complex if anything

Comment: why is it simpler? i still has to think about owned or borrowed. no? with rc , assuming no cycles , i just use rc and don't think about it , true?

Comment: @hulkingtickets it's not simpler because Rust is designed around owned and borrowed pointers as the preferred, "Rustic" way to go and using RC or GC (while possible) is less convenient by design.  I don't know what language you're coming from but C#, for instance, has this in reverse: it lets you use unsafe code for when you need a more direct control of memory, but doing so looks "foreign" and not particularly idiomatic. Coming from C to C# you would think that using unsafe pointers is "easier" just because it's more familiar but it's not.

Answer (score 2):

Rust is not a Garbage Collected language. All Memory is `free()`d deterministically.

```
fn get() -> Vec<i32> {
    vec![1, 2, 3] // <--- v is allocated here
}

fn main() {
    let v = get();
    for i in v {
        println!("{}", i)
    }
    // <--- v is free()d here
}
```

If you do need reference counted types, use an [`Rc<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html). If you pass the object to multiple threads, you will have to use an [`Arc<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html) instead. You **cannot** accidentally use an `Rc<T>` over thread boundaries, because the compiler will error out if it detects such use.

Rust `Rc<T>` and `Arc<T>` are reference counted data types that don't detect cycles. If you create a cycle with `Rc<T>` or `Arc<T>`, that memory will not be `free()d` and you will leak memory.

Note that `Arc` stands for "**Atomically** Reference Counted" and not "**Automatically** Reference Counted" as it does in Objective-C or Swift :)